# Questions about a question

Tags: discussion, questions, etiquette

I have a question about my Software Recommendations Stack Exchange post: [server hosting for communicating with APIs - preferably free](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/80465/server-hosting-for-communicating-with-apis-preferably-free)

I have 3 questions:

- What can I do for improving the above question?
- What are these:

```
 <!-- Do not remove or edit -->
<!-- Note: Questions not about your post will be deleted -->
```

- Sorry for asking late - is the above type of posts allowed?

Comment: Welcome!  Where did you see the two comments (the strings within `<!--` and `-->`)?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket on the markdown-editor of the post - is it normal?

Comment: Interesting.  To my knowledge, that is not normal, but maybe it appears in specific cases.  Which browser were you using, and on which OS?  Did the browser have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Chrome windows 7, yes.

Comment: That's really odd.  Chrome is a common browser (not that I would recommend it!) and Windows 7 is common as well.  Nothing about either that should cause an issue.  And JS being enabled was my other thought.  Hmmm... is your version of Chrome up to date?  Any browser extensions installed that could be causing an issue?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket it should be common, not a bug.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your last comment.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket that lines I saw should be normal - they were probably auto generated. When I created this question, I only had the chance to question-in-meta about my question not just discuss about any thing in the meta. together with the: _I have a question about my Software Recommendations Stack Exchange post: server hosting for communicating with APIs - preferably free_ at the start - it was also probably generated automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!-- Do not remove or edit -->
<!-- Note: Questions not about your post will be deleted -->
```

I can answer that: you need [5 reputation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) on the main site to participate here on Meta. The only exception is when you want to [ask something about your own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274518/295232), which is indicated by that automatically generated blurb of code. Without it, you probably can't submit the post.

Comment: So that blurb is generated automatically?

Comment: @VScode_fanboy yes it is.

Comment: That's why it said to enter my post Id - I thought it was for a security/verification-that-this-guy-posted-something/spam feature... EDIT: [umm?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/questions-about-a-question/2965?noredirect=1#comment6436_2964)